# Using TBBC Money/Currency Bundle for Symfony 2.8

Tags: php, forms, currency, money-format, symfony-2.8

i'm trying to implement TBBC Money/Currency Bundle in my application but it doens't work. i think the problem come from my controller and twig file. I'm a bit lost with the documentation of this bundle.

Any help would be appreciated!

This my config.yml

```
tbbc_money:
    currencies: ["USD", "EUR"]
    reference_currency: "EUR"
    decimals: 2
    enable_pair_history: true
    ratio_provider: tbbc_money.ratio_provider.google
twig:
debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
form:
        resources:
            - 'TbbcMoneyBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'
```

post.php

```
/**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price_amount", type="integer")
     */
    private $priceAmount;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price_currency", type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $priceCurrency;

 /**
     * get Money
     *
     * @return Money
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        if (!$this->priceCurrency) {
            return null;
        }
        if (!$this->priceAmount) {
            return new Money(0, new Currency($this->priceCurrency));
        }
        return new Money($this->priceAmount, new Currency($this->priceCurrency));
    }

    /**
     * Set price
     *
     * @param Money $price
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setPrice(Money $price)
    {
        $this->priceAmount = $price->getAmount();
        $this->priceCurrency = $price->getCurrency()->getName();

        return $this;
    }
```

PostType.php

```
->add('price', 'tbbc_money')
```

new.html.twig

**(i'm sure this part of code is wrong i have to replace it by something else ??)**

```
 <div class="form-group form-group-lg form-group-icon-left">
                                                                    <i class="fa fa-plane input-icon"></i>
                                                                    <label>price</label>
                                                                    {{ form_widget(form.price, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control',} }) }}
                                                                    {{ form_errors(form.price) }}

                                                                </div>
```

Postcontroller.php

**(i don't know what exatcly should i put in my controller.)**

```
<?php

namespace FLY\BookingsBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use FLY\BookingsBundle\Entity\Post;
use FLY\BookingsBundle\Form\PostType;

/**
 * Post controller.
 *
 * @Route("/post")
 */
class PostController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Lists all Post entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="post")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $findEntities = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Post')->findAll();
        $entities  = $this->get('knp_paginator')->paginate($findEntities,$this->get('request')->query->get('page', 1),9
        );
        return array(
            'entities' => $entities,
        );
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Post entity.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="post_create")
     * @Method("POST")
     * @Template("FLYBookingsBundle:Post:new.html.twig")
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $entity = new Post();
        $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('post_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
        }

        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to create a Post entity.
     *
     * @param Post $entity The entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createCreateForm(Post $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new PostType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('post_create'),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));



        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to create a new Post entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new", name="post_new")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function newAction()
    {
        $entity = new Post();
        $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

        return array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Finds and displays a Post entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="post_show")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function showAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Post')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Post entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing Post entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="post_edit")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function editAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Post')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Post entity.');
        }

        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }

    /**
    * Creates a form to edit a Post entity.
    *
    * @param Post $entity The entity
    *
    * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
    */
    private function createEditForm(Post $entity)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new PostType(), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('post_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
            'method' => 'PUT',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));

        return $form;
    }
    /**
     * Edits an existing Post entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="post_update")
     * @Method("PUT")
     * @Template("FLYBookingsBundle:Post:edit.html.twig")
     */
    public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Post')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Post entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isValid()) {
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('post_edit', array('id' => $id)));
        }

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }
    /**
     * Deletes a Post entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="post_delete")
     * @Method("DELETE")
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entity = $em->getRepository('FLYBookingsBundle:Post')->find($id);

            if (!$entity) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Post entity.');
            }

            $em->remove($entity);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('post'));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to delete a Post entity by id.
     *
     * @param mixed $id The entity id
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createDeleteForm($id)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('post_delete', array('id' => $id)))
            ->setMethod('DELETE')
            ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Delete'))
            ->getForm()
        ;
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

i did had this in my controller:

```
 public function myAction()
    {
        $moneyFormatter = $this->get('tbbc_money.formatter.money_formatter');
        $price = new Money(123456789, new Currency('EUR'));

        // best method (added in 2.2+ version)
        \Locale::setDefault('fr_FR');
        $formatedPrice = $moneyFormatter->localizedFormatMoney($price);
        // 1 234 567,89 €
        $formatedPrice = $moneyFormatter->localizedFormatMoney($price, 'en');
        // €1,234,567.89

        // old method (before v2.2)
        $formattedPrice = $moneyFormatter->formatMoney($price);
        // 1 234 567,89

        $formattedCurrency = $moneyFormatter->formatCurrency($price);
        // €
    }
```

then i got this error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Money\Money could not be
>   converted to string") in
>   src\FLY\BookingsBundle\Resources\views\Post\show.html.twig at line 30.

This is my line 30 in show.html.twig

```
<span class="price"><small>Price</small>${{ entity.price }}</span>
```